# Select ComboBox.Item by string

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox called `comType_1`, which contains certain selectable strings. I have a variable `k.Type_1`, which contains the desired string.

Example:

`k.Type_1` contains "Test". `comType_1` contains an Item called "Test". How do I select this item?

I've tried multiple things, and none of them worked:

```
comType_1.SelectedValue = k.Type_1;
comType_1.SelectedValue = comType_1.Items.IndexOf(k.Type_1);
comType_1.SelectedItem = comType_1.Items.Equals(k.Type_1);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and this application is a WPF-application.

Comment: `comType_1.SelectedItem = k.Type_1;` should work, providing both the items in `comType_1` and `k.Type_1` are strings. If they are data objects though, things are slightly different.

Comment: selected item has to be referentially present in combobox items to be selected when you set SelectedItem

Comment: @Rachel The left one is an object and the right one is a simple string. That might be the problem.

Comment: @Muds How can I check if that's the case?

Comment: the itemsource must have the item you want to select, so one way can be selectedItem = itemsSource.First(p=>p.ID = yourItem.ID)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update the ComboxBox-Tag to include the SelectedValuePath=Content,

Example:

```
<ComboBox Name="combo1" SelectedValuePath="Content">
```

Then you can perform the assignment:

```
  comType_1.SelectedValue = k.Type_1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to bring any change. I've tried it, but when I debug it, the SelectedValue remains null. :(

Answer (score 0):

You said the ComboBox Items are Objects, while you are trying to set the `SelectedValue` to a string.

A ComboBox compares items by reference when trying to set the `SelectedItem`, so your string is never going to match the Objects in the ComboBoxes.

I'd recommend setting the `SelectedValuePath` to the property on your object containing the string, and then you can set the `SelectedValue` to a string as well.

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comType_1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

```
comType_1.SelectedItem = "Test";
```

As an alternative you could overwrite the .Equals of your object so it correctly compares against a string and returns true (not really recommended, and if you do you probably want to overwrite `GetHasCode()` as well)

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    { 
        if (obj == null) 
            return false; 

        if (obj is string)
            return (string)obj == this.Name;

        if (obj is MyClass)
            return ((MyClass)obj).Name == this.Name); 

        return false;
    }
}
```

A third option would be to cast your ComboBox Items into your objects and check against your string for the correct object, then set `SelectedItem`

```
var items = comType_1.Items as ObservableCollection<MyObject>;
if (items == null)
    return;

foreach(MyObject item in items)
{
    if (item.Name == k.Type_1)
    {
        comType_1.SelectedItem = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Of the 3 options, I'd recommend the first one.